# How to Align Footer Text on the Right and on the Left?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text on the left and on the right side of my footer. The problem is that the text on the right falls a line below the text on the left. I want them to be even on the same line. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for the help!

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kc6AL/

### HTML

```
<!--Footerline-->
<div id="footerline">
<img src="http://s21.postimg.org/l6t6akypj/line.jpg"/>
</div>
<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer">
<h3 class="copyright">Copyright Stuff.</h3>
<h3 class="social">Social Links.</h3>
```

### CSS

```
#footerline {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    max-width: 980px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

h3 {

font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-weight : 300;
            font-size : 14px;
            color : #000;

}

.copyright {

    text-align: left;
}

.social {

    text-align: right;

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've forked your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/82ZU8/

the key here is to float the `<h3/>`s

**CSS**

```
.copyright {
    float: left;
}

.social { 
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer">
    <h3 class="copyright">Copyright Stuff.</h3>
    <h3 class="social">Social Links.</h3>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Note that you must *clear* the floated blocks, so the footer div will be fixed.

The reason that the text-align approach doesn't work in the way you will expected, is because `<h3 />` is a block element, so it will fill the entire width and causing the next `h3` to go to next "line". Giving the `float` to a block element, will cause the element to shrink to its content and allowing other elements to be aside of it.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Really appreciate it! I chose your answer as the best one, because not only did you help explain what I had done wrong, but you were the only one to actually mention clearing the floated blocks. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Just change your `text-align` to `float` for both `.copyright` and `.social` and you're golden.

**EDIT** Here's a jsFiddle demo with some unnecessary stuff removed: http://jsfiddle.net/kc6AL/6/

Answer (score 1):

Do this: (Add the floats to your css)

```
.copyright {
 float:left;
 text-align: left;
}

.social {
 float:right;
 text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use one h3 and float the social icons within that head tag.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/kc6AL/1/)

```
<h3 class="copyright"><span class="social">Social Links.</span>Copyright Stuff.</h3>
```

CSS

```
.social { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `display: inline;`
to your h3 element.
see this: `http://jsfiddle.net/kc6AL/3/`

for more information: http://learnlayout.com/display.html